# jQuery address book like plugin with item details for dectionary

Tags: jquery

I need a jQuery plugin (open source/free), which has a list with live search for word like filter something like List.js. The additional functionality i need is once user clicks/taps on any word,I want to show the details/meaning of selected word.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the List.js with some customization in my code.